# SQL command to set all Wordpress user nicknames in bulk / at once

Tags: sql, wordpress

I used an import service to import users from the OpenCart platform to a WordPress installation. Unfortunately, when this happened, all imported users ended up with the same "Nickname" as their "UserNames". Because wordpress does not allow for a Nickname to be the same as a Username, when users attempt to update their passwords, they are unable, as wordpress won't save when the nickname is the same as the username.

So, as a fix of sorts, I thought a workaround would be to run an SQL command on the database to simply reset all registered nicknames to something generic like "GenericNickname" or similar.

I'm not good with SQL, so I'm asking for a recommendation on what command I would run to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Is this SQL Server? I just tested this out updating 100 rows into a test database. You could do something like this where its updating each row with the counter being the key from 1 to 100.

```
DECLARE @counter INT

SET @counter = 1

WHILE @counter <= 100
  BEGIN
      UPDATE users_table
      SET    nickname = 'GenericNickname'
      WHERE  users_key = @counter;

      SET @counter = @counter + 1
  END
```

EDIT:

Or you could use a cursor to just go row by row and update it:

```
DECLARE @userKey INT
DECLARE user_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT dbo.users.user_key
  FROM   dbo.users

OPEN user_cursor;

FETCH next FROM user_cursor INTO @userKey;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      UPDATE dbo.users
      SET    dbo.users.nickname = 'GenericNickname'
      WHERE  dbo.users.user_key = @userKey;

      FETCH next FROM user_cursor INTO @userKey;
  END;

CLOSE user_cursor;

DEALLOCATE user_cursor;

go
```